# Keycloak custom PasswordHashProvider, salt change on each connection

Tags: java, keycloak, provider, salt

I am trying to create a custom PasswordHashProvider.
I succeeded in creating the component, the algorithm is working, the password saved in the database is correct.

A Salt is stored in a database, but I don't understand how. I thought it was the base 64 salt, but it doesn't match.

```
database secret_data : {"value":"v8Po+hMGZbS2tWr4IGRXqy3FJyQIavjsrpXHwomWHwRRs+iRVInd+9naF681EENm76lF1omK+BqsPIRrtKH1VQ==","salt":"DEiO17h4/+6gwzxn"}
database credential_data : {"hashIterations":5000,"algorithm":"message-digest"}
```

I add logs in the console when creating a password and when connecting a user. The salt is generated, stored, but the one retrieved during connection is different on each try.

When I register the user secret :

```
New salt : [B@7bb894a0
```

When I try to connect the user :

```
Existing salt: [B@d433036
// retry connection
Existing salt: [B@355bae9a
```

**Does anyone know how salt is stored?**

My class (for tests I force iterations to 5000) :

```
import org.keycloak.credential.hash.PasswordHashProvider;
import org.keycloak.models.PasswordPolicy;
import org.keycloak.models.credential.PasswordCredentialModel;

import java.util.Base64;
import java.security.MessageDigest;
import java.security.SecureRandom;
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;

import java.math.BigInteger; 
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException; 

public class MessageDigestPasswordHashProvider implements PasswordHashProvider {
    private final int defaultIterations;
    private final String providerId;
    private byte[] salt;

    public MessageDigestPasswordHashProvider(String providerId, int defaultIterations) {
        this.providerId = providerId;
        this.defaultIterations = defaultIterations;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean policyCheck(PasswordPolicy policy, PasswordCredentialModel credential) {
        int policyHashIterations = 5000;
        return credential.getPasswordCredentialData().getHashIterations() == policyHashIterations
                && providerId.equals(credential.getPasswordCredentialData().getAlgorithm());
    }

    @Override
    public PasswordCredentialModel encodedCredential(String rawPassword, int iterations) {
        iterations = 5000;
        byte[] salt = generateSalt();
        this.salt = salt;
        System.out.print("New salt : ");
        System.out.println(salt);
        String encodedPassword = encode(rawPassword, iterations);

        return PasswordCredentialModel.createFromValues(providerId, salt, iterations, encodedPassword);
    }

    @Override
    public String encode(String rawPassword, int iterations) {
        iterations = 5000;
        byte[] salt = this.salt;
        System.out.print("Salt fonction encode :");
        System.out.println(salt);
        String salted = rawPassword + "{" + salt.toString() + "}";
        byte[] digest = getSha512(salted.getBytes());
        System.out.println(iterations);
        for (int i = 1; i < iterations; i++) {
            digest = getSha512(concat(digest, salted.getBytes()));
        }

        return Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(digest);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean verify(String rawPassword, PasswordCredentialModel credential) {
        this.salt = credential.getSalt();
        System.out.print("Existing salt: ");
        System.out.println(this.salt);
        String encodedPassword = encode(rawPassword, credential.getHashIterations());
        return encodedPassword.equals(credential.getValue());
    }


    private static byte[] generateSalt() {
        SecureRandom random = new SecureRandom();
        byte salt[] = new byte[12];
        random.nextBytes(salt);
        return salt;
    }
    @Override
    public void close() {

    }
    public static byte[] getSha512(byte[] value) {
        try { 
            MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-512"); 
            byte[] messageDigest = md.digest(value); 
            return messageDigest;
        } 
        catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) { 
            throw new RuntimeException(e); 
        } 
    }
    public static byte[] concat(byte[] a, byte[] b) {
        byte[] c = new byte[a.length + b.length];
        System.arraycopy(a, 0, c, 0, a.length);
        System.arraycopy(b, 0, c, a.length, b.length);
        return c;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> A Salt is stored in a database, but I don't understand how. I thought
> it was the base 64 salt, but it doesn't match.

It is based 64.

> The salt is generated, stored, but the one retrieved during connection
> is different on each try.

The problem is this:

```
System.out.print("New salt : ");
System.out.println(salt);
```

you are not print the actually content of the salt you are print the object "salt".

Try instead:

```
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(this.salt));
```